# Remove repeated concurrent characters in ORACLE 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, replace, oracle10g, regexp-replace

I have an aggregated varchar2 column, containing scans done, in Oracle 10g. An example being:

```
My_Column
XXXOABBOABBBBOABBBOABBBOABBBOABBBOOABUXXX
```

I need to remove repeated concurrent characters, viz. I need to convert above string to:

```
My_Column
XOABOABOABOABOABOABOABUX
```

I need the relative order of each character to be conserved
How can I do that?

I'm thinking of using nested REPLACE() functions to clean the string but I'm looking for a less messier alternative

Comment: i would look at the regexp_substr functionality, it's very powerful so you can probably do something with that

Comment: As davegreen says you can use regexp_substr with a regular expression like "(\\w)\\1+"
Regards
Giova

Comment: Thanks @davegreen100. Let me test it out.

Comment: Thanks @Giova. Let me test it out.

Comment: @Giova Nope, that won't work. It would return `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **REGEXP_REPLACE**.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA(str) AS(
  2  SELECT 'XXXOABBOABBBBOABBBOABBBOABBBOABBBOOABUXXX' FROM dual
  3  )
  4  SELECT str, regexp_replace(str, '(.)\1+','\1') new_str FROM DATA;

STR                                       NEW_STR
----------------------------------------- ----------------------------
XXXOABBOABBBBOABBBOABBBOABBBOABBBOOABUXXX XOABOABOABOABOABOABOABUX

SQL>
```